# Can't access attributes through Has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

Tried to dumb down my models to show the important stuff it seems like things are missing let me know.

I'm trying to access the Owner of a session via `@session.owner` in my view. The owner is associated with an attendee and all the attendees are associated with the session via a `has_many`.

It seems like `self.attendees` does not return any records. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance if you can help!

Cheers,
Tyler

Session Model

```
class Session < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendees

  def owner
    self.attendees.each do |attendee|
      if attendee.role == "Owner"
        "#{attendee.user_id}"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Attendee Model

```
class Attendee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :session

end
```

Comment: can you please use `annotate` https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models and show us the model's fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that stand out. Firstly, the way you have implemented the `owner` method is not very efficient having to query for each record and check the role attribute. The association can be defined using Active Record Association methods. E.g. you can define a scope when declaring associations.

In order to investigate your issue, that is, `session.attendees` is not returning any records, I recommend the following:

1. Verify that you are following the rails convention and have the correct reference column. `Attendee` should have `session_id` column.
2. Write some specs, or at the very least load the rails console and verify that your `has_many :attendees` association is working as expected by creating some test records and seeing some records returned. This will most likely reveal any problems with your code.

Next, declare your "session has owner" association by using active record associations. Think about what you want here: should `session.owner` return the attendee record or the user record (in our example you indicate that attendee belongs to a user?) Assuming that `session.owner` returns an Attendee record, your association may look like this: `has_one :owner, -> { where role: 'Owner' }, class_name: 'Attendee'`. (Please note this is an untested example).

For more information on has_one associations see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Comment: Thanks for your insight. This is a good point! I assume I could then further define other Sessions in a similar way Like session.admin, session.member? Also I left out a model for Role to keep it simple. My attendee model has a role_id column that references the Role model. Any more insight on how to link that? Could I just go where role_id == '1' where 1 gets pulled from another sql call or is there an easier way to go about that?

Comment: Yes you could do that. Also, you can adjust the association scope to handle a more complex role association. Have a play around with active record associations and see if you can figure it out. Here is a clue - the association scope can contain any active record query interface methods e.g. `has_one :owner, -> { joins(:role).where(roles: {name: 'Owner'}) }`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1):

In your case `each` will continue work after find `owner` and will return `nil`.

```
class Session < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendees

  def owner
    user_id = nil
    self.attendees.each do |attendee|
      if attendee.role == "Owner"
        user_id = "#{attendee.user_id}"
        break
      end
    end

    user_id
  end

end
```

I've rewrite your code to use `sql` approach to find `owner`.

```
class Session < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendees

  def owner
    self.attendees.find_by(role: "Owner").try(:user_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hrm... still having no luck with it. It is returning a blank value. I can see the SQL command happening correctly in my terminal and when I run it in workbench the record is there. It just doesn't want to give the value in my app ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This worked in the end had some problems with my database or something that I've sorted out.

Comment: It is worth noting that it is good practice when naming methods to think about what it is doing as well as what is being returned. In the example above, the `owner` method returns the wrong data type, that is, the user id. We would expect `session.owner` to return the owner object and therefore allowing daisy chaining such as `session.owner.name`. If you intend on returning the id then the method should be named `session.owner_id` for example, just as `session.owner?` would return a boolean.